# Historical Prices Immediately Following Bitcoin Halving

Tags: exchange-rate, reward-schedule, price-volatility

I searched here for posts on historical price movements following Bitcoin halving but didn't find much.  I found some [old posts](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4796/what-happens-once-the-mining-reward-gets-cut-in-half) that inquired about the *anticipated* price changes expected for future halvings, but my question is not speculative in nature, but about what has *actually happened* to the price of bitcoin during past halving events.  Can anyone provide a brief summary of what has happened within a few days or weeks to BTC price (or even of other relevant cryptos) in the past when a having has occured?

Comment: Maybe you could do some of the preliminary research yourself?  Historical Bitcoin prices are easy to find (see other questions on this site) as are the dates of the two halvings so far.

Comment: Well of course I could do that, and indeed I've thought about it.  But pulling all the raw data in and analyzing it is not something I had hoped to dedicate a ton of time to.  I'm just looking for a brief summary if anyone happens to know off the top of their head really what happened.  I'm not looking for anything terribly scientific or thoroughly researched.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The halving dates can be found at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Controlled_supply (2012-11-28 and 2016-07-09) and sites like https://bitcoincharts.com/charts/ will let you graph the price over arbitrary time periods.  That seems like it may be enough for your purposes without needing to analyze raw data or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First halving happened on 2012-11-28, the price was around $12, after the event the prices started to rally and by April 10th, 2013 it reached over $250, after which it crashed to around $60.

Second halving happened on 2016-07-09, the price was around $575, after the event it fluctuated for a couple of months and then we know what happened next.. $20k top and now it is around $3.5k

The third halving will happen approximately on May 25th 2020
Source and countdown: https://www.bitcoinblockhalf.com/

You can check the dates and see how the price acted on this chart:
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=BITSTAMP:BTCUSD

Answer (score -1):

Afterr historical max price ~3k$ BTC on june'17 BTC fall down due to fork effects expectations. Few days next to fork BTC began rising as ability to get more BCH for holding more BTC wile halving ends. After that was rally till dec.17 max.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Thanks for your contribution, but I don't see how it answers the question, as there was no [halving](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Controlled_supply) in 2017.  (That's not the same thing as a fork.)